# Next.js - Why I get hydration error in my header component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, next.js

I am working on a job portal, I get user authentication using JWT and store it in local storage. I get hydration error in my header component when authenticated and if I reload my web page. I don't know how to figure out the problem as I am new to next.js.

Header.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";
import Dropdown from "react-bootstrap/Dropdown";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

import { logout } from "../actions/userActions";

const Header = ({ acclink, acc }) => {
  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const logoutHandler = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* Dark navbar: Light links against dark background */}
      <Navbar
        as="header"
        className="mb-5 navbar-stuck"
        bg="dark"
        variant="dark"
        fixed="top"
        expand="lg"
      >
        <Container>
          {/* Logo (Brand) */}
          <Link href="/" passHref>
            <Navbar.Brand className="me-2 me-xl-4">
              <Image
                src="/images/Apt-Job-logo.svg"
                width={116}
                height={32}
                quality={100}
                alt="Apt Job"
              />
            </Navbar.Brand>
          </Link>

          {/* Mobile menu toggle */}
          <Navbar.Toggle
            aria-controls="navbarNav"
            bsPrefix="ms-auto navbar-toggler"
          />

          {/* Action button */}

          {userInfo ? (
            <Nav.Item
              as={Dropdown}
              bsPrefix="d-none d-lg-block order-lg-3 my-n2 me-3"
            >
              <Dropdown.Toggle
                as={Nav.Link}
                className="dropdown-toggle-flush d-flex py-1 px-0"
              >
                <Image
                  alt="User"
                  src="/images/user.png"
                  width={40}
                  height={40}
                  quality={100}
                />
              </Dropdown.Toggle>
              <Dropdown.Menu align="end" renderOnMount variant="dark">
                <Dropdown.Item className="d-flex align-items-start border-bottom border-light px-3 py-1 mb-2">
                  <div className="ps-2">
                    <h6 className="fs-base mb-0 text-light">{userInfo.name}</h6>
                    <div className="fs-xs py-2">{userInfo.email}</div>
                  </div>
                </Dropdown.Item>
                {userInfo.isEmployer ? (
                  <Link href="#" passHref>
                    <Dropdown.Item>Action link</Dropdown.Item>
                  </Link>
                ) : (
                  <Link href="/user/profile" passHref>
                    <Dropdown.Item>Profile Settings</Dropdown.Item>
                  </Link>
                )}

                {userInfo.isEmployer ? (
                  <Link href="#" passHref>
                    <Dropdown.Item>Employer action</Dropdown.Item>
                  </Link>
                ) : (
                  <Link href="#" passHref>
                    <Dropdown.Item>Another action</Dropdown.Item>
                  </Link>
                )}
                <Dropdown.Divider as="div" />
                <Dropdown.Item onClick={logoutHandler}>Signout</Dropdown.Item>
              </Dropdown.Menu>
            </Nav.Item>
          ) : (
            (acc == "usr" || acc == "emp") && (
              <Link href={`${acclink}/login`} passHref>
                <Button
                  variant="link"
                  size="sm"
                  className="btn-light d-none d-lg-block order-lg-3"
                  // onClick={() => router.push("/login")}
                >
                  <i className="fi-user me-2"></i>
                  <span className="d-none d-sm-inline">Sign in</span>
                </Button>
              </Link>
            )
          )}

          {acc == "usr" && (
            <Link href="/postresume" passHref>
              <Button
                variant="primary"
                size="sm"
                className=" rounded-pill order-lg-3 ms-2"
              >
                <i className="fi-plus me-2"></i>
                Post<span className="d-none d-sm-inline"> Resume</span>
              </Button>
            </Link>
          )}

          {!userInfo && acc == "" && (
            <>
              <Link href="/user" passHref>
                <Button
                  variant="link"
                  size="sm"
                  className="btn-light d-none d-lg-block order-lg-3"
                >
                  <span className="d-none d-sm-inline">For Users </span>
                  <i className="fi-arrow-long-right ms-2"></i>
                </Button>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/employer" passHref>
                <Button
                  variant="link"
                  size="sm"
                  className="btn-light d-none d-lg-block order-lg-3"
                >
                  <span className="d-none d-sm-inline">For Employers </span>
                  <i className="fi-arrow-long-right ms-2"></i>
                </Button>
              </Link>
            </>
          )}

          {/* Responsive Navbar nav (Menu) */}
          <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarNav" className="order-md-2">
            <Nav className="navbar-nav-scroll" style={{ maxHeight: "35rem" }}>
              <Nav.Item>
                <Link href="/user" passHref>
                  <Nav.Link>Find Jobs</Nav.Link>
                </Link>
              </Nav.Item>
              {userInfo && userInfo.isEmployer ? (
                <Nav.Item>
                  <Link href="#" passHref>
                    <Nav.Link> Post Jobs</Nav.Link>
                  </Link>
                </Nav.Item>
              ) : (
                userInfo &&
                userInfo.isEmployer == false && (
                  <Nav.Item>
                    <Link href="#" passHref>
                      <Nav.Link>Applied Jobs</Nav.Link>
                    </Link>
                  </Nav.Item>
                )
              )}

              {(!userInfo && acc == "usr") ||
                (acc == "emp" && (
                  <Nav.Item className="d-lg-none">
                    <Link href={`${acclink}/login`} passHref>
                      <Nav.Link>
                        <i className="fi-user me-2"></i>
                        {"Sign in"}
                      </Nav.Link>
                    </Link>
                  </Nav.Item>
                ))}
             
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
};


export default Header;
```

I am sure hydration error is because of header, I removed header component from a page and tested when authenticated, it shows no hydration error when I include header when authenticated and reload the page it shows hydration error.

Comment: Can you show us the full error/stack trace that you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Hydration error can also cause if there's a syntax or HTML semantic error in your component.

Mine was caused by having nested buttons.

Comment: Confirmed, if you're sure your HTML is fine, then it's most likely most external library.